# glsl What happens if infinity multiply on 0?

Tags: glsl, glsles

In my glsl vertex shader, lets say I have following code:

```
float len = k/0;
```

Now len is infinity. What happens if I multiply it on 0? Does result remains "infinity", or it becomes 0? In other words, what happens if infinity multiply on 0? Mathematically should be 0...

Comment: As far as I've read/remembered, the result becomes *undefined*.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, it is not well-defined, because infinity is not well-defined (at least, in the normal number system). The output of `inf*0` on a IEEE-754-compliant system (which I *think* GLSL guarantees, perhaps with the exception of denormals?) is NaN.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc308050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information on the effect of various operations on various special floating-point values.

Comment: I ask what I have on  (float/0) * 0 = ? Not the output of inf/0 .

Comment: Sorry, typo. Meant to say, `inf*0 = NaN`.